# If I have a users table but want e-mails to be usernames, should I simply have email/password as columns?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Or should I have username, email, password and set save username also as email?

edit: I am not using email as the pk but am using a unique index on the email

I feel like if I decided to change to openid/usernames I can still do that in the future by adding another column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do email/password. And if you ever want to add usernames you can upgrade it then. No need to use extra fields if they're the same and you don't need them.

Comment: Didn't think of mentionning that. I'd do an autoincrementing value for the primary key (userid)

Comment: OP mentioned he was using a unique index anyway so that's good. varchar as PK = big no no

Comment: Plus it doesn't let users change their email in the future. Glad you mentionned I had disregarded the primary key.

Comment: That's cool, sometimes it's best not to assume in this case we would have been right if we didn't mention it but it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well just have the email column since it functions as both, no point in repeating data in your table. Just remember DO NOT SAVE PASSWORDS AS CLEARTEXT :) Also you should have a Primary Key id column